# ido-completing-read - how to bind C-j to another action?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido

I am using ido-completing-read to select songs from a database.

```
(song (ido-completing-read "Play: " db))
```

How do I use keys like `C-j` here to select songs in a different way. I just need to know if
the song was selected by pressing `RET` or `C-j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could examine `last-command-event` right after calling `ido-completing-read`: it will be `10`(`?\n`) for <kbd>C-j</kbd>, `13`(`?\r`) for <kbd>RET</kbd>.